# A different proof of the insolubility of the quintic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm familiar with the "standard" proof using Galois theory that there is no general formula for solving an equation of fifth (or higher) degree using radicals (i.e. arithmetic and root-taking). However, now I'm wondering if other proofs of different nature were found (in particular ones relying on analysis rather than algebra).

What sparked my interest was seeing a description of the solution of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th degree equations via something that looked like discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: It _is_ the discrete Fourier transform.  But the DFT is a purely algebraic notion; no analysis necessary.

Comment: Could you please give a link to such a DFT proof?

Comment: @George: for the cubic formula it's given in the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Lagrange.27s_method .  For the quartic formula it should be similar but one might have to split into cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the content of the Abel-Ruffini theorem (whose proof predates Galois')

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

A topological proof may be found in this paper.

https://www.tmna.ncu.pl/static/files/v16n2-02.pdf

Comment: If the link for the topological proof does not work, try this one: https://www.tmna.ncu.pl/static/files/v16n2-02.pdf